# C# using regular expressions to replace malformed XML close tags

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a malformed xml file which is generated with incorrect closing tags as follows.

```
<Root>
.
.
<Question id='1' type='text'>London</Question id='1' type='text'>
<Question id='2' type='radio'>4</Question id='2' type='radio'>
<Question id='3' type='check'>6</Question id='3' type='check'>
.
.
</Root>
```

I need to refine this XML file with propper closing tags as follows.

```
<Question id='1' type='text'>London</Question>
```

In summary close tags like,

```
<Question id='some id' type='some type'> should be replaced with </Question>
```

There are hundreds of tags in the file. How can I use string operations with RegEx to process that file in order to create a well-formed XML file.

Thanks,

Chatur

Comment: You should totally drop that and use a tolerant XML Parser.

Comment: Why not use regexp in notepad++ in order to refactor closing tags instead of using C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `str` is the malformed XML string:

```
string fixed = Regex.Replace(str, @"</([^\s]+)[^>]+>", "</$1>");
```

A very useful thing to test regular expressions is [Regex Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/) from Rad Software. It's free, it's fully .NET-compatible and it has built-in help.

Comment: Thanks Artem... it worked for close tags except the root. The only issue is it replces the root close tag as </Roo>

Comment: @chatura: Change the pattern to `</([^\s]+)\s+[^>]+>` to fix the problem with `</Root>`.